# importing project from intelij 12 to android studio beta

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

My project worked fine in intelij and I wanted to try it in the android studio beta, however when importing it android studio says

`Error:The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle. Please use version 1.10.
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)
<a href="fixGradleElements">Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project</a><br><a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a>`

This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12+'
}
}
    apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
//compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAds.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2')
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
compile files 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'


}

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 16
}
}
```

previously in intelij I had been using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:.5+` and I guess this is no longer supported. So what I'm wondering is what is the correct setting I need? Changing it to .12+ like was suggested then causes "Unable to find any references to the Android Gradle plugin" when I press the suggested quick fix. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your android studio version? This happened to me but was fixed after the update. You will have to rebuild your project and ensure you've set the new target gradle build.

Comment: Yes previously I was using the first preview version available last year, and I have updated to the beta version (.8) which I am trying to use now

Comment: After updating, did you also go to the sdk manager and update your build tools? I had to do that also

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by deleting all of the generated build and gradle files... android studio then automatically downloaded newer version of gradle and the issue was resolved.